# Python Scattertext tf.idf categories problem

Tags: python

I use scattertext for Python to analyze tweets from two different classes. I have a column called "modularity_class" and each tweet is marked as either 0 or 1. I face a problem in the following snipped of code

```
term_freq_df['0_corner_score'] = corpus.get_corner_scores('0')
term_freq_df.sort_values(by='0_corner_score', ascending=False).iloc[:10]
```

I get the following exception:

```
Exception: Invalid category: 0, valid: [1, 0]
```

Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Could you show the code you're using to come up with the data frame and corpus objects?

Note that the category names you use to create your corpus should be strings.

Comment: Thanks Jason. That was the mistake. Changed numbers to strings and worked fine. 
By the way, it works excellent with non-western languages, and is amazingly useful.